# How to change environment values dynamically

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, laravel-5.1

How to change environment values dynamically in Laravel 5.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize the `Config` facade to change values at runtime. For example:

```
Config::set('app.timezone', 'America/Chicago');
```

At the end of the request, that value is no longer set.

You can also use the `config()` helper method and pass it an array so it knows it needs to be set:

```
config(['app.timezone' => 'America/Chicago']);
```

See also: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/#configuration

Answer (score 2):

```
Config::set('app.timezone', 'America/Chicago');
```